# Why is Ruby printing object.method before string?

Tags: ruby, methods

```
class Bike
  attr_accessor :color, :gear_numbers, :style

  def spin
    puts " spins! Woosh!"
  end
end

gw = Bike.new
gw.color = "white"
gw.gear_numbers = 11
gw.style = "compact"

puts "This bike is #{gw.color} and it has #{gw.gear_numbers} gears. Oh, and it has a #{gw.style} design. Did I mention that my bike #{gw.spin}?"
```

Using IRB, this is what I get:

```
**spins! Woosh!                                                                                                                 
This bike is white and it has 11 gears. Oh, and it                                                                             
has a compact design. Did I mention that my bike ?**
```

Why is "spins! Woosh!" coming BEFORE the string and why isn't it *IN* the string?

Answer (score 4):

Because you're not returning the string from your method, you're printing it directly.

To do what you want to do, simply remove the `puts` from your `spin` method and you're good to go.

```
class Bike
  attr_accessor :color, :gear_numbers, :style

  def spin
    "spins! Woosh!"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Because to interpolate the string Ruby needs to call `spin`. Then Ruby includes the return value of the `spin` method (which is `nil`, because `puts` returns `nil`) into the string and prints the generated string.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that string interpolation needs to be fully complete before the string is passed through to the main `puts` you have there. As part of figuring out what's in there it must execute each of the methods referenced in the order which they appear.

Your `spin` method causes an *immediate* `puts` and it doesn't return anything, as that's how `puts` works. If you want to supply a string to go in there, simply leave it:

```
def spin
  " spins! Woosh!"
end
```

Think of this string interpolation:

```
"a #{b} c #{d} e"
```

This is roughly equivalent to:

```
"a " + b.to_s + " c " + d.to_s + " e"
```

Where those `.to_s` calls are to force it into a string. You'd expect `b` and `d` to be exercised before the whole string is returned.

When anticipating what code will do, trace execution to the bottom first, then work back up. Simple programs work in very predictable ways.

Comment: "Simple programs work in very predictable ways." … and side-effects work in complex ways, hence programs using side-effects are not simple. As is nicely demonstrated by this question, which shows again why side-effects should be avoided as much as possible.